# To prove ; $pa:=a+a+... p $ times $=0 , \forall a \in R$ and $a^p=a , \forall a \in R$ for some prime $p$ then the ring $R$ is commutative

Tags: ring-theory, positive-characteristic

If in a ring $R$ , $\exists $ prime $p$ such that $pa:=a+a+... p $ times $=0 , \forall a \in R$ and $a^p=a , \forall a \in R$ , then how to prove that $R$ is commutative ? I would not want to use something big like Jacobson's theorem concerning $a^{n(a)}=a$ , it would be overkill . Please help

Comment: I'm not certain the proof is going to be substantially simpler for prime exponents than it is for general expontents. It might be slightly simpler than the one where exponent can vary by element.

Comment: This is essentially [already asked](http://mathoverflow.net/q/29590/19965) on mathoverflow